# Единственная ориентация приложения в Java Android

Tags: java, android, orientation

### Единственная ориентация приложения в Java Android

---

Я работаю над приложением-таблицей на Java для android  и приложение подразумивает использование только в горизонтальном режме. Я добавил только `landscape` версию `.xml` файла, но при запуске приложения вертикально - приложение крашеться.

---

Как сделать, чтобы при запуске приложения - оно запускалось в горизонтальном режиме и при повороте устройства - Java не пыталась выбрать вертикальный `.xml` файл и приложение не крашилось?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 вариант - установка ориентации в файле манифеста

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<manifest
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="ru.site.a1">
 <application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
   </intent-filter>
  </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

> 2 вариант установка ориентации программно

ориентация портретная

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

ориентация альбомная

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
package ru.site.a1;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
 }
}
```